# Unable to load "maps" library in R

Tags: r

I am trying to load the library "maps" in R. I get the error message:

> "Loading required package: maps Error in value[3L] :
>   Package ‘maps’ version 2.3.9 cannot be unloaded:  Error in
>   unloadNamespace(package) : namespace ‘maps’ is imported by ‘fields’ so
>   cannot be unloaded"

NOTES. This problem has only started since I installed the most recent version of R (version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30) -- "Kite-Eating Tree") and RStudio (Version 1.1.423).

Any clues anyone?

Comment: Did you update your packages after updating to R 3.4.3? I'd restart RStudio then run this command: `update.packages(ask = FALSE, repos = "http://cran.rstudio.org", checkBuilt = TRUE)`

Comment: Maps version 2.3.9 is quite ancient (e.g. still has USSR in the world map), so you should definitely consider updating your packages. You have package "fields" already loaded, and that has also loaded maps v2.3.9 as a required package.

Is it possible you have two versions of "maps" installed in different paths?